# Sourcetree showing files as modified right after checkout?

Tags: git, cygwin, atlassian-sourcetree

I checked out a Git repo in Cygwin on Windows. Than I installed Sourcetree and opened the same (local) repository. I was surprised to see that Sourcetree marked many files as modified.

I've opened files in Notepad++ (before I opened the repo in Sourcetree) and saw the line endings are LF.

When I execute `git config --list` I get `core.autocrlf=false`.

When I clone the repository from within Sourcetree, all is OK (neither Cygwin nor Sourcetree show any modified files).

I also checked the file permissions, but they seem to be the same, so Cygwin seems not to change the permissions.

What could be the reason for such behavior? Cygwin seems to be doing something that Sourcetree considers a file change?

Cygwin git version: 2.21.0
Sourcetree git version: 2.24.1

Comment: likely the Cygwin/Posix way and standard Windows way of the two git to handle the file permission and termination is not compatible. My 2c€ , use one of them, do not mix.

Comment: Could you see the output of SourceTree Git's `git status` or `git diff`? If you can't access that, try portable Git for Windows, I think it should show the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved the issue:

```
git config core.filemode false
git config core.autocrlf true
```

(Executed from the Cygwin command line.)

Strangely enough, the same commands with `--global` switch did not help, meaning those two commands need to be executed every time a new repository is cloned.

Comment: On Windows, you can directly edit the global .gitconfig file which is located at C:\Users\user_name. The two options you mention should be under the `[core]` key.